# Iterate hashmap's in ArrayList Freemarker

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap, freemarker

I am having a parent `ArrayList` and 2 child `HashMap`:

```
List countries = new ArrayList();

Map<String, String> data_dummy = new HashMap<String, String>();
data_dummy.put("name", "abc");
data_dummy.put("surname", "xyz");

Map<String, String> data_dummy2 = new HashMap<String, String>();
data_dummy2.put("name", "def");
data_dummy2.put("surname", "pqr");
countries.add(data_dummy);
countries.add(data_dummy2);
```

I am trying to iterate with syntax :

```
 <#list countries as category>
   <#assign keys = countries[category]?keys>
   <#list keys as values>
     ${keys[values]}
  </#list>
</#list>
```

Its not working, please tell me how to resolve this.
Thanks
Amit

Comment: add your iterate code

Comment: i am trying to iterate it in freemarker template engine with code : 

<#list countries as category>
   <#assign keys = countries[category]?keys>
   <#list keys as values>
     ${keys[values]}
  </#list>
</#list>

Thats my iterate code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try something like:

```
 <#list countries as category>
    <#assign keys = category?keys>
    <#list keys as key>
         ${category.get(key)}
    </#list>
 </#list>
```

Comment: it works for me with little trick : 

<#list countries as category>
    
    <#list category?keys as key>
         ${category[key]}
    </#list>
 </#list>

Thanks SMA

Comment: seems to be for an older version of freemarker, `category[key]` is what works as of version 2.3x

Comment: @RichStone agreed and appreciate your response, see when this was answered and when this question was raised. Answer doesn''t get updated automatically with every release of libraries.

Comment: @SMA sorry if I haven't followed the correct rules here, but as the version is never mentioned anywhere, it might confuse people trying to replicate this. Would it have been the more correct way, if I edited the answer directly, e.g. with a hint to the version?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have mixed up and missed a few things, but I see you have realized that in your comment since that. But, the other (currently accepted) answer is not what anyone should do. Since your keys are `String`-s, you can just use `someMap[someKey]`. And even for non-string keys `someMap.get(someKey)` only works with a specific configuration setup, which is strongly discouraged as it mixes the real `Map` keys with the method names. A total mess. `someMap?api.get(someKey)` is the better approach nowadays, as then the method names don't have to pollute the key namespace. (Note that it still needs some extra configuration due to backward compatibility constraints; the Manual covers that well.)